# W40k book about Tyranids and astartes

Tags: story-identification, books, warhammer-40k

I'm trying to find a specific W40k book.
I remember reading a snippet in white dwarf a long time ago.

It was from the perspective of imperial guard stationed on a farm planet and Tyranids were attacking.

Then space marines arrived in drop pods and the author went to great effort to describe the awe the IG character experienced.

Anyway, any assistance would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The story was in White Dwarf 254 when the Tyranids were released that year.

The story is *The Fall of Malvolion* by Dan Abnett. This was a short story and was never turned into a book.